# How to login user with node.js express backbone.js mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, express

I am really new to nodejs and backbone  its so confusing

The login:

On the client side I use backbone.

**Model**

```
var testModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'api/test',
    defaults:{
        login:false,
        apikey:{},
    },

    initialize:function(){
        this.bind('change:apikey',this.onApiKeyChange,this);
        // this.set({'apikey': localStorage.getItem('apikey')});
    },

    setApiKey:function(apikey){
        localStorage.setItem('apiKey', apikey);
        this.set({'apikey':apikey});
    },

    onApiKeyChange:function(){
        // console.log(this.toJSON())
        //login here
    }
});
```

**View**

```
var testView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'#content',
    events:{
        'submit #loginForm':'login',
    },

    login:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.model.setApiKey({name:this.$('input[name=username]').val(),password:this.$('input[name=password]').val()});
    }
})
var test= new testView({model:new testModel()});
```

So when user submits the form the model gets changed and that triggers the `onApiKeyChange()`, if the user login then `onApiKeyChange()` should update the model with user detail. I don`t know how to do that, how does backbone send a request like this?

The server side:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var routes = require('./routes');
 var http = require('http');
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');


 var app = express();

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
 var User = mongoose.model('User',new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    password:String,
 }));

 app.configure(function(){
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
 app.set('view engine', 'jade');
 app.use(express.favicon());
 app.use(express.logger('dev'));
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
 app.use(express.cookieParser());
 app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));
 app.use(express.methodOverride());
 app.use(app.router);
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/api/test', someFunction());

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

The server side is just basic express app.js, I don`t know how to use the session.

I know this may be a basic problem, but I just don`t get it. Please give me some advice or tell me some easy tutorials for beginner.

Answer (score 7):

I personally use [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) to make the authentication, only after the user is authenticated he can access the "single page app" where I use backbone. Here is a project that was a great help for me [LostAndFound](https://github.com/ArnaudRinquin/LostAndFound)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will be useful for you ...

https://github.com/etaque/node-backbone-mongo-showcase.git